# PHP Reflection: get constant's doc comment

Tags: php, reflection, constants

It is easy to retrieve the doc comment for methods and properties. But what about constants? There is no `ReflectionConstant` class which would allow me to call `getDocComment()` on them. It's possible to get the list of constants and their values as strings using `ReflectionClass::getConstants` but that's all. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To my best knowledge there is no built-in function or class that allows you to retrieve class constant doc comments. However, you can use `token_get_all($classContent)` and write your own parser.

Here is what I have come up with, after needing this feature as well:

```
/**
 * Simple DocComment support for class constants.
 */
class ConstDoc
{
    /** @var array Constant names to DocComment strings. */
    private $docComments = [];

    /** Constructor. */
    public function __construct($clazz)
    {
        $this->parse(new \ReflectionClass($clazz));
    }

    /** Parses the class for constant DocComments. */
    private function parse(\ReflectionClass $clazz)
    {
        $content = file_get_contents($clazz->getFileName());
        $tokens = token_get_all($content);

        $doc = null;
        $isConst = false;
        foreach($tokens as $token)
        {
            if (!is_array($token) || count($token) <= 1)
            {
                continue;
            }

            list($tokenType, $tokenValue) = $token;

            switch ($tokenType)
            {
                // ignored tokens
                case T_WHITESPACE:
                case T_COMMENT:
                    break;

                case T_DOC_COMMENT:
                    $doc = $tokenValue;
                    break;

                case T_CONST:
                    $isConst = true;
                    break;

                case T_STRING:
                    if ($isConst)
                    {
                        $this->docComments[$tokenValue] = self::clean($doc);
                    }
                    $doc = null;
                    $isConst = false;
                    break;

                // all other tokens reset the parser
                default:
                    $doc = null;
                    $isConst = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    /** Returns an array of all constants to their DocComment. If no comment is present the comment is null. */
    public function getDocComments()
    {
        return $this->docComments;
    }

    /** Returns the DocComment of a class constant. Null if the constant has no DocComment or the constant does not exist. */
    public function getDocComment($constantName)
    {
        if (!isset($this->docComments) || !isset($this->docComments[$constantName]))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return $this->docComments[$constantName];
    }

    /** Cleans the doc comment. Returns null if the doc comment is null. */
    private static function clean($doc)
    {
        if ($doc === null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        $result = null;
        $lines = preg_split('/\R/', $doc);
        foreach($lines as $line)
        {
            $line = trim($line, "/* \t\x0B\0");
            if ($line === '')
            {
                continue;
            }

            if ($result != null)
            {
                $result .= ' ';
            }
            $result .= $line;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: works great: i had to add  if (count($token) >1)   before the   list($tokenType, $tokenValue) = $token;   to not make it crash for some files

Comment: Thanks. Added the corner case to above example.

Answer (score 1):

There is now an API for this, you need to use `getReflectionConstants` instead of `getConstants` in order to access all the extra metadata:

```php
class Foo {
    /** I am a comment */
    const BAR = "bar";

    /** Other comment */
    const BAZ = "baz";
}

$rc = new ReflectionClass(Foo::class);
foreach($rc->getReflectionConstants() as $rcc) {
    print("{$rcc->getName()} ({$rcc->getValue()}) - {$rcc->getDocComment()}\n");
}
```

Which prints:

```
BAR (bar) - /** I am a comment */
BAZ (baz) - /** Other comment */
```