# Clear all comments but leave PHPDoc

Tags: php, regex

I'm creating a debugging/doc script and I want to ignore all the standard comments but leave the PHPDoc in tact.

The code I was using was:

```
    // Get file into an array line by line
    $line = file($file);

    // Trim all empty space and # or // comments
    array_map(function($v) {
        $v = trim($v);
        $v = preg_split("/\/\/|#/", $v)[0];
        return $v;
    }, $line);
```

The problem being, this would still leave the multi-line C-style comments like:

```
/*
This
means
nothing
*/
```

So I believe I'll have to read in the entire file, find every `/*` while ignoring `/**` (PHPDoc) and removing everything until `*/`.

So the regex would need to be multi-line.  I'm open to solutions using `file()` but I think `file_get_content()` would be more practical with the finding of C-style open and close comment tags on separate lines.

Comment: Try this - Reflection if its OOP.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103019/php-reflection-get-constants-doc-comment, and http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix, thank you.  That's look like a great starting point using that class / token_get_all like akond suggested.

Comment: Yes, I would prefer using reflection over token_get_all only because it adds a bit of abstraction, but somthings i think can only be done using token_get_all, or regx's you could do the same thing with regx and a simple lexer type setup but that is a whole other topic lol

Answer (score 1):

I reckon the best way about it is to use `token_get_all()`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to have to dig more into this.  I appreciate the heads up.